# Blank Spaces also Bind When Binding a Dropdown list

Tags: asp.net

when i Bind the dropdownlistHostelRoomType, it binds with empty spaces left above.. i dont have any idea why this is happening. help me getting out from this issue please..    My Code:

```
<div>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Hostel Details </legend>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelHostelRoomType" runat="server" Text="Room Type"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListHostelRoom" runat="server" DataTextField="HTypeName"
                        DataValueField="_HRTypID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownListHostelRoom_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewHostelRoom" runat="server">
                    </asp:GridView>
                </fieldset>
            </div>

private void FillHostelRoomType()
            {
                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=_uniManagement;Integrated Security=True");
                string sqlDropdownHostelRoom = String.Format("SELECT [_HRTypID], [HTYPeNAME] FROM [_HOSTELS_Room_TYPE]");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlDropdownHostelRoom);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                DropDownListHostelRoom.DataSource = dt;
                DropDownListHostelRoom.DataBind();
            }



protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownListHostelRoom.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
            DropDownListMemberType.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
            FillHostelRoomType();
            FillHostelMember();
            base.OnInit(e);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, there are empty spaces in the source database.  In your SQL statement, you should be able to use [RTRIM()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx) around the field names to eliminate the issue.

Another possible cause might be that the field in the DB is CHAR with a specified length.  If that is the case, even if there are no spaces, retrieving it will always give you exactly that many spaces, so SQL Server will pad the end with enough blank spaces to fit.

For example, a field defined as CHAR(10) with the data `"DAVID"` in it will be returned as `"DAVID     "` (David appended with five blank spaces to bring the total up to 10)

Either way, RTRIM should fix it.

```
string sqlDropdownHostelRoom = String.Format("SELECT [_HRTypID], RTRIM([HTYPeNAME]) AS HTYPeNAME FROM [_HOSTELS_Room_TYPE]");
```

Comment: Give the RTRIM command a shot - it should only take a few seconds, and see if it works.  If not, I'll delete this.

Comment: well, my code was also right but i dont know why sometimes this VisualStudio behaves crazy..